# How to keep track of user by passing Firebase reference?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So I am constructing an iOS app where it requires the user to sign up and log in. After they log in, the login view controller segues to a table view controller where the user enters data. After the user confirms the data info they entered, it then segues to a delivery information view controller where they put in shipping address info. My question is how can I make it to where the data the user entered and the shipping address info they entered stay referenced to that specific user? So that way if another user logs in, their data amount and shipping address information is stored under their own node and is seperate from any other users? Just imagine like any food delivery app, I'm curious to know how they keep track of each user's order, delivery address, etc. attached to that specific user? Right now every time I try to make a new reference with a different user it replaces the old reference even if it was stored by a different user.

```
 import UIKit
 import FirebaseDatabase
 import FirebaseAuth

class LogInController: UIViewController {

var ref: DatabaseReference!


@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!


func placeholders() {
    emailField.placeholder = "Enter Email"
    passwordField.placeholder = "Enter Password"
}






@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in




        let userID: String = (user?.uid)!
        let userEmail: String = self.emailField.text!

        self.ref.child("Users").childByAutoId().setValue(userEmail + " " + userID)




        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }

        else {
            print("User logged in with UserID of: " + (user?.uid)!)
        }
        })
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "signedIn", sender: self)


}



@IBAction func signoutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("User has logged out...")
   try!  Auth.auth().signOut()
}



@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            return
        }

            print("User created with UserId of: " + (user?.uid)!)


    })
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let flavorsVC = segue.destination as? FlavorsController {
        flavorsVC.ref = ref
        let userEmail = emailField.text
        flavorsVC.email = userEmail!

    }
}







override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    placeholders()
    ref = Database.database().reference()

}
```

View controller I'm trying to save data in:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class FlavorsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var bookieFlavors = ["Chocolate Chip", "Sugar w/o icing", "Sugar w/ icing", "Peanut Butter", "Honey", "Shortbread", "Ginger", "Double Chocolate", "Macadamie Nut", "Oatmeal Raisin", "Snickerdoodle"]
var amount = [Int]()
var bookieTotal = Int()
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var flavorRef: DatabaseReference!
var email = String()





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for _ in self.bookieFlavors {
        self.amount.append(0)
    }
    flavorTable.delegate = self
    flavorTable.dataSource = self

    //database references
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    flavorRef = Database.database().reference()



}

func emptyAmount(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button Held, Amount Emptied")
    self.amount[sender.tag] = self.amount[sender.tag] - (self.amount[sender.tag] + 1)
    let cell = self.flavorTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? FlavorTableCell
    cell?.bookieAmount.text = "= \(self.amount[sender.tag])"

}


@IBAction func bookieButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.amount[sender.tag] = self.amount[sender.tag] + 1
    let cell = self.flavorTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? FlavorTableCell
    cell?.bookieAmount.text = "= \(self.amount[sender.tag])"
   // print(amount[sender.tag])

    self.bookieTotal = amount.reduce(0, +)
    print(bookieTotal)
}




@IBOutlet weak var flavorTable: UITableView!


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int    
{
    return bookieFlavors.count

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FlavorTableCell


    //flavor label configuration
    cell.flavorLabel.text = bookieFlavors[indexPath.row]

    //amount configuration
    cell.bookieAmount.text = "= \(self.amount[indexPath.row])"
    cell.bookieButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.bookieButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bookieButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.bookieButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(emptyAmount(_:)), for: .touchDownRepeat)

    return cell

}

@IBAction func registerBookieAmount(_ sender: Any) {
    print(bookieTotal)

    let amount: Int = bookieTotal
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    if ((user) != nil) {


    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code and data structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Now this is a bit difficult without knowing your data structure, but it looks like every time a user signs in, a new node is created for them using this code here:

`self.ref.child("Users").childByAutoId().setValue(userEmail + " " + userID)`

Instead of using `childByAutoId()`, which creates a unique push id, make `userID` the key:

`self.ref.child("Users/\(userID)").setValue(["email": userEmail])`

Then you can listen for the value of `ref.child("Users/\(userID)")` to get the user's saved data. You can also write any data to that same path, such as the shipping address you mention.

As an aside, I'd recommend calling `self.ref.child("Users/\(userID)").setValue(["email": userEmail])` inside `createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)` because this node doesn't need to be rewritten every time the user logs in.

Comment: How could I write more data to that same path? Currently my code just replaces the data but I just want to add to the reference as you mention in your answer.